# Setting up a system of linear equations to determine the number of classes offered

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Every math class at Bronze High school has $31$ students and every science class has $18$ students. The school offers $4$ more math classes than science classes. If the school has $418$ students, how many of each class does the school offer?

---

So far I have one equation $31x+18y=418$. $X$ is the math class and $Y$ is the science. I have trouble figuring out the second equation I am going to need since this is a system of equations problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE! What have you tried and what's giving you difficulty? Please share your thoughts on the problem, so that people can give help that's relevant to you.

Comment: So far I have one equation 31x+18y=418. X is the math class and Y is the science. I have trouble figuring out the second equation I am going to need since this is a system of equation problem. Any ideas? Thank you for your comments. Really helps!

Comment: +1 for showing some of your own ideas on solving the question .

Comment: @mikoyan you didnt vote up

Comment: just to let people know, this question was **not** migrated from meta, so the downvotes here are not the downvotes from meta.

Comment: @AngelaFernandez: edit your attempt into the question and some of the downvotes *might* go away.

Comment: @draks...: perhaps mikoyan's +1 was only on Angela's comment. When the improvement is made to the question, perhaps the +1 will also.

Comment: It was on the comment, I felt the upvote should be associated with the effort she had made.

Comment: The problem is not really well posed.  There appears to be an implicit assumption that every student is in math or science, but not both.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ denote the number of math classes and $Y$ denote the number of science classes.

Then the word problem gives:

$(1)$ $31X+18Y=418$

$(2)$ $X-Y=4$

with the assumption that students take either a math class or a science class and not both.

By $(2)$ we have $X=Y+4$. Substituting this into $(1)$ gives

$418=31(Y+4)+18Y=49Y+124$.

So $49Y=294$. So $Y=6$. This tells us that $X=Y+4=10$.